# Pandoc HTML to DOCX using template

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to convert HTML to DOCX file using Pandoc, I have created a  reference docx file for template to apply styles for my output DOCX file.

While converting HTML elements to DOCX , hr tag is generated as double line in DOCX output, since by default DOCX applies double lines for Horizontal rule/line.
 I need to apply styles for the HR rule in DOCX template so that my output document will have the HR styles applied.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--reference-doc and let us know if you run into any specific problems.

Comment: I have gone through the manual but couldn't find the steps for Horizontal rule styles

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is an old question which was never answered. It remains an issue with me as well. I've never figured out how to force HR's to single lines in the DOCX, they always show as double lines. I've added a line to my reference docx and made sure it is set to a single line but it does not fix the resulting docx.

Comment: @mb21 and Shawn: there seems to be an issue in pandoc's translation process, as it doesn't use the "horizontal ruler"-style defined in the reference.docx file at all, but instead <hr> is rendered as a drawing, a box with very little height, showing as double lines.

Comment: @isync if you know the docx XML that should be generated for an hr (and have tested it in various word and libre office versions), then feel free to open a pandoc issue or comment on https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2573

Comment: @mb21 aw, yikes. Just a casual pandoc user here. I only wanted to help track this down a little inch... with my findings... yet can't really help. O_O.